# Command Prompt Separation of text by Character

Tags: batch-file, cmd

while I was on Stack Exchange to figure out how to separate text by character, I thought I could simply modify the solution I found (which is supposed to divide by line), but I was unable to.  Can anyone show me how to fix this code with explanation.  Thank you!  Here is the code I found:

```
set i=0
for /F %%a in (test.txt) do (
    set /A i+=1
    set array[!i!]=%%a
)
set n=%n%

for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do echo !array[%%i]!
```

Comment: "*Write this code for me*" is not a question.

Comment: What does "separate text by character" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script was supposed to put each line of test.txt into a separate variable.

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "i=0"
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%a In ("test.txt") Do (
    Set/A "i+=1"
    Set "line[!i!]=%%a"
)
For /L %%a In (1,1,%i%) Do Echo=!line[%%a]!
```